# The basic probabilistic relation of collision theory

Tags: collision, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In "Classical Mechanics", John R. Taylor gives this basic relation of collision theory

$$N_{sc}=N_{inc}n_{tar}\sigma$$

for firing projectiles into targets.

- $N_{sc}$ is the number of projectiles that are scattered
- $N_{inc}$ is the number of incident projectiles
- $n_{tar}$ is the "target density" (the number of targets per unit area)
- $\sigma$ is the cross-sectional area of each target

Taylor claims that since $N_{sc}$, $N_{inc}$, and $n_{tar}$ are all easily-measurable, $\sigma$ can be computed.

I understand how $N_{sc}$ and $N_{inc}$ could be measured, but without prior knowledge of a target's constitution, how would $n_{tar}$ be known?  For example, in Rutherford's day, how could he have known how many gold nuclei were in a given area of gold foil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rutherford knew the atomic weight of gold and Avogadro's number; with those plus the areal mass and thickness of the gold foil he could calculate the density of targets per unit area.

For some history with dates on the development of these techniques see: http://science.jrank.org/pages/634/Atomic-Weight-History.html

Comment: Thanks Peter. This leads to a follow-up question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242123/how-were-atomic-weights-originally-measured